# Why can't PostgreSQL identity columns be used in CREATE TYPE?

Tags: postgresql, identity, postgresql-14

My impression is that each PostgreSQL table has a corresponding composite type associated with it. But it seems that the PostgreSQL identity column cannot be used in a `CREATE TYPE` statement:

```
=> CREATE TYPE _t_type AS (id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GENERATED"
LINE 1: CREATE TYPE _t_type AS (id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTI...
                                          ^
```

, while it can be used in a `CREATE TABLE`:

```
=> CREATE TABLE _t_table (id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
CREATE TABLE
```

*Is there a fundamental reason why identity columns cannot or should not be used in `CREATE TYPE` statement?*

(This is with PostgreSQL 14 beta1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to have an identity column in a data type. After all, a data type does not hold data. So yes, that is not possible.